# Convert a Redis aof to rdb

Tags: redis

I have an Redis `aof` file. Is there a way to convert it to `rdb`?

I was thinking of starting a Redis instance with `appendonly yes`, load my `aof` file and then ask Redis to dump an `rdb`. Unfortunately I'm not that Redis fluent. Is it possible to be done?

Comment: Totally doable - just do a `BGSAVE` (or `SAVE`) after the AOF is loaded to make an RDB dump of the data.

Comment: @ItamarHaber is it going to be stored on the default dump.rdb? Is there a way to check the path?

Comment: `CONFIG GET dir` and `CONFIG GET dbfilename`